# Null or throw exception

Tags: java, arrays, null

```
public class Learner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dataArr = new String[4];
        dataArr[1] = "Bill";
        dataArr[2] = "Steve";
        dataArr[3] = "Larry";
        try{
            for(String data : dataArr){
                System.out.print(data+" ");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

The book states this will print:
null Bill Steve Larry

This confuses me as I thought accessing any data with null will throw a NullPointerException.  Is there ever a time when an exception is thrown when accessing an array with null values?

Or is system.out.println(), the saving grace?  Can you access any null value with a for loop, as long as your not say calling data.length() on it?

Comment: You can "handle" a null reference, you just can't call methods on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation is defined in the JLS as a *safe* operation when an operand is a null reference, ie it doesn't throw any Exception (which would be the case if it attempted to describe the object with `.toString()`) and the text `"null"` must be used instead.

The safety check is **not** run when unboxing is needed:

```
Integer val = null;
int err = val + 1; // throws NPE
```

Just for curiosity, accessing any static method on a null reference does not even need the check because the binding happens at compile time:

```
public class NullRefStatic {

    public static void test() { // <-- static method
        System.out.println("It works");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        NullRefStatic target = null;
        target.test(); // <-- Prints "It works"
    }
}
```

Comment: So i'm guessing that's something I'm going to have to learn from experience, is which methods are safe operations to perform on null objects

Comment: Actually it's easier: accessing a null reference **always** throws a NPE. String concatenation only checks **before** calling toString()

Comment: So in a way, the print has a null check already built in, but usually expect the NPE. Makes sense.  The static method is interesting info too.

Comment: The print() method *also* checks for null's - but your specific code sample does not exercise this check because the  `null + " "` expression must be fully evaluated before and it returns `"null "` (note the trailing space)

Answer (score 0):

So there it is printing out the value of the object, which would be null in this case.

A null pointer exception would occur if you tried to use it's functions or access any properties, because those don't exist yet, hence the null pointer exception.